# Can I use the Backup and Migrate module to back up Drupal 6 and restore in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm new to the Drupal environment and I'm looking to upgrade a website from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. I would like to know if I am able to use Backup and Migrate module to back up Drupal 6 and restore in Drupal 7?

If not, I'm aware of Migrate and Drupal-to-Drupal data migration modules. Are there any recommendations for an easy migration? The website itself has many content types, blocks, views, and content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer no.
What you can do is to upgrade your current Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. It really depends on how complex your Durpal 6 site is. As far as I know, if you didn't use a lot of "hooks", the upgrading process will be smooth, or you need to rewrite some codes. Generally, it is a work of one week. After upgrading the site to Drupal 7, you can use the data&migration module. Good luck.